# Trying to create a 'trie' in Javascript. Can't figure out why my method isn't adding the children correctly

Tags: javascript, trie

Here is the 'constructor' function as well as the 'inset' method I created...

```
function Trie(value) {
    this.value = value;
    this.endOfWord = false;
    this.children = {};
}

Trie.prototype.insert = function(string) {
    let node = new Trie(null);

    for(let character of string) {
        if (node.children[character] === undefined) {
            node.children[character] = new Trie(character);
        }
        node = node.children[character];
    }
    node.endOfWord = true;
};
```

Here is the test case I created...

```
let trie = new Trie;
trie.insert('hello');
console.log(trie)
```

the output for the console log is...

```
Trie { value: undefined, endOfWord: false, children: {} }
```

based on my input into the 'insert' function I was expecting...

```
Trie { value: 'h', endOfWord: false, children: {value: 'e', endOfWord: false, children: {value: 'l', endOfWord: false, children: {value: 'l', endOfWord: false, children: {value: 'o', endOfWord: false, children: {}}}}} }
```

Any clues or tips as to why this isn't adding the children correctly?

Thanks for your time!

Comment: You have created a new `Trie` node in the `insert` method but not used it anywhere.

Comment: what should be the expected result?

Comment: How am I not using it when I am using bracket notation to add a property?

Comment: You do not use `node` anywhere outside of that method You are not using the instance children, you create a new one to manipulate

Comment: Isn't your intent for `.insert()` to _insert_ `node` as the children of `trie`? I think that is what you've missed that @decpk is pointing out.

Comment: I am trying to understand... I thought I was creating a new node and passing in the current character being iterated on with "node.children[character] = new Trie(character);" I don't get how I am NOT inserting a node into the children lol... Thank you for responding though!

Answer (score 3):

You need to use the children on the instance you are on, not the new instance you created.

So when you do `let node = new Trie(null);` you are creating a new instance. You are adding the children to that, not the current instance you already created.

```js
function Trie(value) {
    this.value = value;
    this.endOfWord = false;
    this.children = {};
}

Trie.prototype.insert = function(string) {
    let node = this;
    for(let character of string) {
        if (node.children[character] === undefined) {
            node.children[character] = new Trie(character);
        }
        node = node.children[character];
    }
    node.endOfWord = true;
};


let trie = new Trie;
trie.insert('hello');
console.log(trie)
```

Answer (score 2):

You are just creating a new `Trie` node and assign all property to it. You are not using it anywhere.

You are considering `node` inside the `insert` function as the object which is calling it and you should assign all the property as a children:

```
let node = this;
```

You can directly use `this` but for simplicity I've just assign the current object to the `node`

```js
function Trie(value) {
  this.value = value;
  this.endOfWord = false;
  this.children = {};
}

Trie.prototype.insert = function(string) {
  const node = this;
  string.split("").forEach((character, index) => {
    if (node.children[character] === undefined) {
      node.children[character] = new Trie(character);
      if (index === string.length - 1)
        node.children[character].endOfWord = true;
    }
  });
};

let trie = new Trie();
trie.insert("hello");
console.log(trie);
```

```css
/* This is not a part of answer. It is just to give the output full height. So IGNORE IT */
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Oh, thanks... What I was trying to do was create a root node! But now that I think about it my insert method would redundantly create a new node with null... at least if it worked lol. Thank you for explaining it! I really appreciate it!